# Can't parse XML generated from a HTTP POST response

Tags: php, web-services, http-post, simplexml

I have this XML response file created by a web service. When I try to parse using SimpleXML nothing happens. Here is the XML Response:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[0] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><NEWCAR_RESPxmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="www.mydomainge.com/SellerMessages"><X_LEAD_ID>1779237289</XL_ID><SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS><CACHED_RESPONSE>false</CACHED_RESPONSE><PRICE>34.9383</PRICE><DealerList><Dealer><BUYER_ID>0000-2127</BUYER_ID><Reservation_ID>1779237289|0000-2961|8f807d03-4b0d-4329-a728-77398957c757|100025</Reservation_ID><Price>34.9383</Price><Name>Dealer Demo 1</Name><State>MI</State><City>South</City><Street>48985</Street><Postalcode>48075</Postalcode><Distance>0</Distance><DealerGroup id="2961" max_post="0" /><Contact><Phone>2483521313</Phone></Contact><Prequalification>true</Prequalification></Dealer></DealerList></NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE>
```

)

This is my code:

```
$context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
file_put_contents("dtx_post_response.xml", $response);
$ResponseXml = simplexml_load_file("dtx_post_response.xml");

$Dealer = $ResponseXml->NEWCAR_RESPONSE->XL_ID;

echo $Dealer;
```

This result in a blank page!

Comment: `<X_LEAD_ID>1779237289</XL_ID>` What's up with this?

Comment: Sorry I misspelled the example

Comment: So we're also assuming that `<NEWCAR_RESP` and `</NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE>` are also typos, and should be `<NEWCAR_RESPONSE>` `</NEWCAR_RESPONSE>`?

Comment: yes, should say <NEWCAR_RESPONSE></NEWCAR_RESPONSE>

Comment: My problem to parse the XML file was caused by the response, the document have a double xml header and the response came with a element named string that should be removed at the HTTP Post Request.

Comment: @berortmedia You can (and are encouraged to) add and accept an answer to your own question, so that it might benefit later readers. Incidentally, this behaviour of one XML document represented as a string inside another XML document is a common result of (lazy) use of ASP.net's built-in web service functionality.